# Zipkin - Is there any more informtaion about creating spans and traces in Java

Tags: java, spring, rest, distributed-system, zipkin

I would like to create my own basic, minimalistic library used for distributed tracing with Zipkin. I will be sending traces via HTTP and nothing more fancy. My question is if there is any more information about this topic than in the Zipkin docs and the source code of Zipkin and Brave? I would like not to rely on Spring Framework. Spring Cloud Sleuth works very well, but my services are not built using Spring. Do you know any resources? Or do you have any ideas where to start doing this?

Comment: I am also trying to do something similar, I am trying to use http call to create annotations for Cs/SR...Let me know if you are able to do with basic http call to zipkin

Answer (score 1):

Instrumenting a library is something that sometimes folks have to do for one reason or another. There are several tracer libraries in Java but the salient points about creating a tracer are either on the website, or issues on the website.

http://zipkin.io/pages/instrumenting.html
https://github.com/openzipkin/openzipkin.github.io/issues/11

OpenTracing also has some nice fundamentals to look at http://opentracing.io/

This isn't a one-answer type of question, in my experience, as you'll learn you'll need to address other things that tracer libraries address out-of-box. For that reason I'd highly suggest joining gitter so that you
can have a dialogue through your journey https://gitter.im/openzipkin/zipkin

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I will check all the links you provided.